# IE doesn't Respect NBSP

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm currently having an issue where I want a label (within a  within a table) to all be on a single line, in IE (firefox seems fine).  But currently its being split into 3:

```
...
<td class="label"><span class="mandatory">* </span>Starting Date:&nbsp;</td>
...
```

**Result:**

```
*
Starting
Date
```

**Desired Result:**

```
*Starting Date
```

Comment: The problem must be localized to your styles. Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/h8WVH/

Comment: What stylesheet rules do you have in place? Also, which version of IE are you using and which rendering mode is IE in (Standards Mode, Quirks Mode, etc)?

Comment: Maybe it's the other way around, `&nbsp` doesn't respect IE ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the `&nbsp;`s in the right places, it should be:

```
<td class="label"><span class="mandatory">*&nbsp;</span>Starting&nbsp;Date:</td>
```

That should be enough, but you might want to try applying `white-space:nowrap` to the element instead.